# Update inner list in object with other collection

Tags: c#

This might be silly, but I was wondering how to update one property in the collection with other type from other collection like this :

I have two collection of values.
One is of type MyType which has property myProperty.
Second is just collection of number which should be assing to myProperty in my first object.

Of course lenght of both collection are the same.

Other word I would like without looping with for each just repleace 
`dailyInputData.Select(x => x.myProperty)` with `valueToUpdate`

I was trying to do it with Zip , but no right idea, and basically I don't know if this is possible?

```
private void Update(List<MyType> dailyInputData, List<double> valueToUpdate)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dailyInputData.Zip(valueToUpdate, (input, val) => new dailyInputData { myProperty = val });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(pair in dailyInputData.Zip(valueToUpdate, (obj, value) => Tuple.Create(obj, value)))
    pair.Item1.MyProperty = pair.Item2;
```

or

```
dailyInputData.Zip(valueToUpdate, (obj, value) => Tuple.Create(obj, value))
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(pair => pair.Item1.MyProperty = pair.Item2);
```

Comment: No problem. Avoid abusing `Tuple` though. It doesn't carry any meaning, the properties' names (`Item1`, `Item2`, etc) are not intuitive, they don't tell you what's inside. But in short scenarios such as this one, using tuples is ok.